# Interdependent Organization charts, Relationship maps and Business process diagrams

Tags: project-management, charts, uml

I’m looking for a recommendation for a software (or possibly a collection of mutually compatible softwares) capable of creating **Organization Charts**, **Relationship Maps** and **Business Process Diagrams**. The software should ideally be capable of the following.

1. Creating a **Hierarchical Organization Chart** structured as "Management" -> "Departments" -> "Department agendas" -> "Individual activities in an agendas" -> "People conducting the activity". Due to the high volume of data, collapsing / expanding functions would be nice.
2. Having a **database with people and their respective activities** so that when a person's name or activities change, the Org Chart also changes.
3. Creating a **Relationship Map** that shows relationships between the Departments based on their agendas.
4. Creating **Business Process Diagrams** in which custom activities as well as Activities defined in the database could be used. Ideally, the names of the people conducting the Activities (taken from the database) be displayed.
5. Exporting the created charts, maps and diagrams to some form of **universal standard** (such as XML).

P.S. Though I am tech-savvy and work in IT, I’m new to Business process management and Business architecture, so please excuse my possibly ignorant description. Any help will be greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [Code demo](https://code.balkan.app/result/interdependent-organization-charts,-relationship-maps-and-business-process-diagrams) for you

[BALKAN OrgChartJS](https://balkan.app/OrgChartJS) supports all functionalities you are asking for

Basically you have 3 options:

- if you are developer use BALKAN OrgChartJS
- if you not developer hire somebody with JavaScript skill and ask him/her to create project using BALKAN OrgChartJS
- if the above are not possible, contact BALKAN App and ask them to create an app for you, they offer development services

[image]

Disclaimer: I'm working at BALKAN App